# Output of `Subsuperscript` in TeXForm?

Tags: expression-manipulation, latex, custom-notation

`TeXForm` can be used to convert *Mathematica* expressions directly to LaTeX. However, this function fails on an expression that has a sub- and a super-script:

```
expr = Subsuperscript[A, a, b]
expr // TeXForm
```

> [image]

My question is:

> Is there an alternative Mathematica construct that would translate the above input to `A_{a}^{b}` under `TeXForm` operation?

Comment: I would report this to Wolfram.

Comment: @Szabolcs I sent them an email about it. Any hints for a workaround?

Comment: I found this page that uses a python script for a workaround:  https://www.lieret.net/2018/01/04/mathematica-latex-bugs/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is to change the default of the following internal variable to [`False`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/False):

```
BoxForm`$UseTemplateBoxForSubsuperscript = False;
```

Then:

```
ToString[Subsuperscript[A, a, b], TeXForm]
```

> "A_a^b"

Another possibility is to teach [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) about "Subsuperscript" [`TemplateBox`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TemplateBox) objects.